# How do you integrate >= statements with numbers in ifelse package? Error in ifelse:

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a responses for each row and several rows. My goal is to have % content in each district. I planned on having finding total content for each district and the total respondents of the study in each district.

This is the code I used:

```
jbnew <- jb %>%
   mutate(content = ifelse(jb$sum.contentcir > 3),1,0)%>%
   nrow(filter(jb))
group_by(jd,district) %>%
   summarise(Num.Totalrespondents =n(),
             Num.totalcontent = sum(content))%>%
   mutate(percent.totalcontent = Num.totalcontent/Num.Totalrespondents)
```

I keep getting this:

```
Error in ifelse(jb$sum.contentcir >= 3) : 
  argument "yes" is missing, with no default
```

My intention for this code, was to say that those who had a sum of 3 of more will then have the "content column" as "1".

Comment: Change to `jb %>% mutate(content = ifelse(sum.contentcir > 3),1,0))`.

Comment: Or, more simply `mutate(content = as.numeric(sum.contentcir > 3))`. `TRUE` will be coerced to `1`, `FALSE` to `0`.

Comment: @GregorThomas actually, for summing, the `as.numeric` is not even mandatory. `mutate(content = sum.contentcir > 3)` shoud do as well.

Comment: what was recommended did seem to work.When I tried this, it worked. does it make sense?                    ` jbnew <- jb %>% mutate(content = ifelse (as.numeric(sum.contentcir >= 3),1,0))`

Comment: The `ifelse` does nothing in that case, @Ani. `as.numeric` already converts the result to 1s and 0s.